Can one parameterize transition rate matrices such that the stable distribution becomes independent of the transition rates?
I am trying to model a problem in which I need to describe a set of continuous time markov chains that depend on some parameter $v$. Thus, for each $v$, let $K(v)$ be $n\times n$ transition matrix describing a continuous time markov chain with stable distribution $\pi(v)$. It holds
$$
\pi(v) K(v) = 0,\quad \sum_{i=1}^n K_{ij}(v)=0
$$
Let us assume that I know $\pi(v)$ and need to construct $K(v)$ that fulfills the condition above. The question is: is there a principled way to parameterize the transition rate matrix as a function $K'(\pi,\theta)$ such that $\theta$ encodes all possible transition matrices that have $\pi$ as stable distribution?
I found a paper that described a solution for the case where we additionally assume the stronger detailed balance condition [1]
$$
\pi_i K_{ij}=\pi_j K_{ji}
$$
In this case, we can find a symmetric matrix $S$ and define $K_{ij}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi_j} {\pi_i}}S_{ij}$ and take the diagonal element such as to sum to zero as before. Thus the upper triangular part of $S$ together with $\pi$ forms a full parameterisation. However, when detailed balance does not hold, I was not able to find a similar parameterisation.
References
[1] Robert T McGibbon , Vijay S Pande "Efficient maximum likelihood parameterization of continuous-time Markov processes", J. Chem. Phys., 2015, Jul 21, 143(3), 034109, doi:10.1063/1.4926516.

One can always parametrize any set by (the elements of) the set itself, using the identity map for the parametrization.

You can parameterize the solutions to $\pi K = 0$ by Gaussian elimination, then eliminate some parameters using the zero row sum constraint on $K$. Generically this should give you $n(n-2)$ parameters. Are you looking for something better than that?

You can parametrize with $\theta$ in the set of all transition matrices, and define $K'(\pi,\theta)$ as the projection onto the convex set of transitions matrices $K$ having $\pi K=0$.
